# Html inside cell contents

Tags: html, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to build  an html string dynamically and show it in the cell inside reactJS' ag grid.

for my example:
In my function file:

```
function myTestFunction(props)
{
myHtmlString=  "<span>a</span>";
myHtmlString +=  "--"
myHtmlString +=  "<span>b</span>";

return (
<div>
{myHtmlString}
</div>
)
};
export default myTestFunction
```

and in my main reactjs file:

```
import MyTestFunction from myTestFunction;
...
{headername: "Test", field: 'test', cellRendererFramework:MyTestFunction}
```

But this is printing the string literally inside the cell in the aggrid...i.e.
`<span>a</span>--<span>b</span>`.

But I need print it as an HTML string instead.i.e. it should print a--b in the cell.
What am I missing here please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return <div>Hey, <strong>you.</strong></div>;
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: createMarkup() }} />;
}
```

Take a look here
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) to converts an HTML string to one or more React elements.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

function myTestFunction(props) {
 myHtmlString=  "<span>a</span>";
 myHtmlString +=  "--"
 myHtmlString +=  "<span>b</span>";

 return (
  <div>
    {parse(myHtmlString)}
  </div>
 )
};
export default myTestFunction
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-elgdfe?file=src%2FApp.js)